# Android (JAVA) error

Tags: java, android, illegalstateexception

I got the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method submitorder(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. As currently written, the question seems to be a bit unclear.

Comment: wow...that sir is one hell of a question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your .xml and look at the `android:onClick` parameter. Did you spell the method name correctly?